# git-TF tfs 2013 Cannot Clone Repo - Ubuntu

Tags: git-tf

The path structure of TFS 2013 for Git Repos is not working.

My path is the following:
http://tfsserver:8080/tfs/DC/_git/PrjName

So when I call the following, it cannot find the repo.

git tf clone http://tfsserver:8080/tfs/DC $/_git/PrjName

If I use a normal git command on Windows, i am able to run the following and everything is fine.

git clone http://tfsserver:8080/tfs/DC/_git/PrjName

What is wrong with my path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got my answer from the developer site.

https://gittf.codeplex.com/workitem/152

"You have a Git repository on a TFS server, while Git-TF is designed to connect o repositories with the traditional TFS version control (i.e. TFVC). You don't need Git-TF in your case. Just use the normal Git."